# Cannot access OpenId UserInfo endpoint on Azure (AADSTS90010: JWT tokens cannot be used with the UserInfo endpoint)

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm trying to access the OpenId UserInfo endpoint for a user on an Office365 Azure tenant, with the following GET:

```
GET https://login.windows.net/common/openid/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJ(...remainder deleted for brevity...)
Host: login.windows.net
```

The response fails with "400 Bad Request", and a more specific error "AADSTS50063: Credential parsing failed. AADSTS90010: JWT tokens cannot be used with the UserInfo endpoint"

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
x-ms-request-id: ef5c8a50-69b5-40f1-ac5f-9c0fc5180aa2
x-ms-gateway-service-instanceid: ESTSFE_IN_6
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer correlation_id="e5c613a0-0a21-40e1-9ef6-    eacf77580608", error="invalid_request", error_codes="[50063, 90010]",     error_description="AADSTS50063: Credential parsing failed. AADSTS90010: JWT tokens cannot be used with the UserInfo endpoint.%0d%0aTrace ID: ef5c8a50-69b5-40f1-ac5f-9c0fc5180aa2%0d%0aCorrelation ID: e5c613a0-0a21-40e1-9ef6-eacf77580608%0d%0aTimestamp: 2015-02-20 14:13:42Z", timestamp="2015-02-20 14:13:42Z", trace_id="ef5c8a50-69b5-40f1-ac5f-9c0fc5180aa2"
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=productionb; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 20 Feb 2015 14:13:40 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

The bearer token used is a non-expired access token that works fine for other operations, such as retrieving Exchange emails.

Furthermore, when I use an identical GET to the openid userinfo endpoint at "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect" (as part of a gmail access scenario), it works fine

Am I doing anything wrong here? Thanks for any help!

Some extra info:

-Already tried using the id_token instead of the access_token, but this makes no difference.

-the Oauth scopes used are "profile email"

-the resources requested are "https://outlook.office365.com/"

-the client application is a native app and has enabled all delegated permissions for both "Windows Azure AD" and "Office 365 Exchange Online"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Azure AD user info endpoint does not support the use of the regular JWT access tokens at this time. Instead, you can acquire a user info specific access token by not specifying any resource in a request to the token endpoint.  You can think of the user info endpoint as a resource in its own right, which requires a special token format.

For example, in the authorization code case:

- GET request to `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?...` without a `resource` parameter, and acquire an authorization_code
- POST request to `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token` using the authorization_code, also without a `resource` parameter.  Receive an access token for the user info endpoint.
- GET request to `https://login.windows.net/common/openid/userinfo` passing the access token in the header as `Authorization: Bearer AAAB(...rest of token...)`

Comment: Tried your approach and indeed, now I can access the userinfo endpoint - thanks.  I'll mark this therefore as the answer.   That being said, it only seems to work if my application accesses my own organization's tenant.  When on the other hand I try to access another tenant (in multitenant scenario), I get an error _AADSTS65001: No permission to access user information is configured for '...removed...' application, or it is expired or revoked_.  This normally the error you would expect when there is no resource specified...

Comment: another observation:  with the tokens for userinfo and regular oauth resources not being the same, and each one requiring a separate authentication flow (prompting the user twice for user/pwd), doesn't this defeat then the purpose of single-sign on for multiple resources?  It doesn't seem logical, does it?

Comment: Is your application pre-configured to request the "Sign me in and read my profile" permission?  (You can find out by looking at the app config page on the Azure management portal.)  Do you experience multiple login prompts?  You should be able to redeem a code/refresh token for an access token to a different resource, assuming that the user has already consented to grant the app access.

Comment: For your first comment - please answer Dan's question re: permissions.  I've verified that the steps in the answer work for multi-tenant apps.  For your second comment - you're right, this is a problem that should be fixed.  However for the time being, the end-user should not see multiple prompts for u/p, only a redirect to AAD & back to the app.  If you want to circumvent these redirects, you can use the auth code you received after user auth to first acquire a token for the user info endpoint, then use the refresh token to acquire any JWTs you need.

Comment: Also, note that almost all the information currently provided via the user info endpoint is available in the claims of the JWT token itself.

Comment: My app has indeed set the permission "sign me in and read my profile" in the Azure management portal and this is also listed as such in the consent dialog.

Comment: I have now tried with a single login prompt, reusing the resulting access code twice (once without specifying resource for userinfo access token, and once with resource for office365 Exchange mail token).  This works now fine for single-tenant. Thanks for pointing out that the same access code can be reused twice for requesting tokens for different resources (I misunderstood that part at first - thought I needed to obtain a different access code for userinfo and non-userinfo case).

Comment: However what still doesn't  work is accessing the userinfo endpoint in a multitenant scenario, in a tenant different from the organization that owns the client application. Still getting the AADSTS65001 error there.  Is there perhaps some special permission that needs to be set by the admin of the foreign tenant?

Comment: Would you mind shooting me an email with the error details and a trace? We can come back with the answer here once we diagnose.

Comment: sure, how do I get your email address?  Alternatively you can contact me via my profile page (altalogix link, then Contact Us) and I'll mail you back

Comment: I am not specify resource but I still get this error AADSTS9001014: JWT tokens cannot be used with the UserInfo endpoint. However, the end point now change to this https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/openid/userinfo

Comment: It seems that if you use https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo as the userinfo endpoint it *does* accept the JWT and give you back user info.

Comment: This thread seems the only relevant one for my problem. However, when I am trying to follow it, I still got no where.
I am using flask along with oauth.remote_app.  After successfully got authorization, I am trying to get the userinfo from the openid endpoint: `microsoft.get('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/openid/userinfo', {'token':request.args.get('token')} )`  Here, I am trying to pass the token I got from the authorization step.   I also tried to replace "common" with tenant id.   
 But All I got is "HTTP Error 400: Bad request "  Can anyone help please?

Comment: Finally figured it out.  There were two problems with my code. 
Firstly, kwargs dictionary should be like `{"Authorization":"Bearer "+request.args.get('id_token'), 'access_token':request.args.get('access_token')}`
secondly, proxies should be passed to the url request.  I ended up using  `import requests; requests.get(some_url, proxies=proxies, headers = headers)` 
where headers include the necessary tokens/authorization arguments, and proxies are my company proxies.