# Cannot access OpenID connect UserInfo endpoint of AzureAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I see that the userinfo endpoint is present on AzureAD OpenID Connect .well-known result. I want to access their UserInfo endpoint. I'm aware I will get the error if used with JWT tokens,

error_description="AADSTS90010: JWT tokens cannot be used with the UserInfo endpoint."

How can I retrieve these non-JWT tokens? I saw a stack overflow thread ([Cannot access OpenId UserInfo endpoint on Azure (AADSTS90010: JWT tokens cannot be used with the UserInfo endpoint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631635/cannot-access-openid-userinfo-endpoint-on-azure-aadsts90010-jwt-tokens-cannot)) that said 'you can acquire a user info specific access token by not specifying any resource in a request to the token endpoint.'

However, I see this:

POST http://login.microsoftonline.com:443/common/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com:443
...
{"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS50001: Resource identifier is not provided.}

Comment: Hi Jeff. Wondering if you were able to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot access OpenId UserInfo endpoint on Azure (AADSTS90010: JWT tokens cannot be used with the UserInfo endpoint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631635/cannot-access-openid-userinfo-endpoint-on-azure-aadsts90010-jwt-tokens-cannot)

Comment: In both authorization request and token request you have the option of mentioning "resource" parameter. If you do that, you will get an access token of JWT. Also, this is a duplicate of above provided link

Comment: In my post, I mentioned that another thread suggests not specifying resource. The above link is the thread I was talking about. But not mentioning 'resource' parameter results in an error - Resource identifier is not provided.

Comment: Also, my question is what sort of tokens are supported at the UserInfo endpoint, if not JWT? How can I get these opaque tokens? I have only received JWT tokens so far.

Comment: @JeffRay I'm seeing the same behavior.  If I don't specify a resource I don't get a token.  This is for an implicit grant app.

Comment: I do not specify the resource but I still get this AADSTS9001014: JWT tokens cannot be used with the UserInfo endpoint